# REACT not starting, because NPM?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I tired to try start my React Project, but I have this response:

```
Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.js
  Searched in: /Users/cabraces/Projects/cesarcabral/portflio/src
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portflio@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the portflio@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cabraces/.npm/_logs/2018-03-07T15_05_46_191Z-debug.log
```

And if I open the file: **2018-03-07T15_05_46_191Z-debug.log**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Users/cabraces/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/cabraces/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.7.1
3 info using node@v8.9.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle portflio@0.1.0~prestart: portflio@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle portflio@0.1.0~start: portflio@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle portflio@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle portflio@0.1.0~start: PATH: /Users/cabraces/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/cabraces/Projects/cesarcabral/portflio/node_modules/.bin:/Users/cabraces/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle portflio@0.1.0~start: CWD: /Users/cabraces/Projects/cesarcabral/portflio
10 silly lifecycle portflio@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle portflio@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle portflio@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: portflio@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/cabraces/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/cabraces/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid portflio@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/cabraces/Projects/cesarcabral/portflio
16 verbose Darwin 17.4.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/cabraces/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node" "/Users/cabraces/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v8.9.4
19 verbose npm  v5.7.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error portflio@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the portflio@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I found on internet many related posts, always everybody suggest that can be my **npm version**, that currently is **npm@5.7.1**.

So, I would like to know if this issue with NPM and React is possible be solved, without downgrade my **npm version**? Any other suggestion how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have an `index.js` in `/Users/cabraces/Projects/cesarcabral/portflio/src`

Comment: yeap .. thanks. @GabrielBleu
this file was missing.

Answer (score -1):

Please check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52028698/2103379.). This might help

If you are using rxjs and typescript libraries there are some compatibility issues in both, which needs to be sorted as mentioned in the link.