# Exit status 3 npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I get the below error when running our CI-build (it's fine on our locals), 
I've tried,

- cleaning the destination folder,
- updating npm to 5.7.1

and still same issue,

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\buildmanager\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   '--environment=CI' ]
2 info using npm@5.7.1
3 info using node@v6.11.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle procom-phoenix-web@1.0.0~prebuild: procom-phoenix-web@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle procom-phoenix-web@1.0.0~build: procom-phoenix-web@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle procom-phoenix-web@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle procom-phoenix-web@1.0.0~build: PATH: C:\Users\buildmanager\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\agent\_work\3\s\Phoenix\Procom.Phoenix.Web\node_modules\.bin;C:\agent\externals\vstsom;c:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\buildmanager\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\agent;C:\agent\bin;C:\agent\bin
9 verbose lifecycle procom-phoenix-web@1.0.0~build: CWD: C:\agent\_work\3\s\Phoenix\Procom.Phoenix.Web
10 silly lifecycle procom-phoenix-web@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'gulp build && cd Phoenix && cd appNext && ng build "--environment=CI"' ]
11 silly lifecycle procom-phoenix-web@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 3  signal: null
12 info lifecycle procom-phoenix-web@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: procom-phoenix-web@1.0.0 build: `gulp build && cd Phoenix && cd appNext && ng build "--environment=CI"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 3
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\buildmanager\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\buildmanager\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:891:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
14 verbose pkgid procom-phoenix-web@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\agent\_work\3\s\Phoenix\Procom.Phoenix.Web
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\buildmanager\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build" "--" "--environment=CI"
18 verbose node v6.11.0
19 verbose npm  v5.7.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3
22 error procom-phoenix-web@1.0.0 build: `gulp build && cd Phoenix && cd appNext && ng build "--environment=CI"`
22 error Exit status 3
23 error Failed at the procom-phoenix-web@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3, true ]
```

p.s there is another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895318/exit-status-1-npm-lifecycle-index-js28516) and status code is different and almost same with no answer.

Comment: Please checkout my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52028698/2103379). This might help. If you are using rxjs and typescript in your project the above could be a possible solution. It seems there is some compatibility issue in both these libraries.

Comment: Hi Reza, how you got a solution for this? I have no rxjs in my project and facing the same issue on CI build.

Comment: @RohitAmbre sorry, it was for almost 2.5 years ago, I don't remember